# Dudas con el Checkout de MercadoPago

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, mercadopago

quiero intergrar el checkout de mercado pago desde javascript sin ningun framework y tengo varias consultas, primero de todo, a la porcion de codigo debajo lo tengo que ejecutar del lado del servidor?, segundo, necesito datos de formulario para que se ejecute correctamente lo de abajo?, solo implemente esto en el html

```
    <form action="/procesar-pago" method="POST">
      <script src="https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/integrations/v1/web-payment-checkout.js"
        data-preference-id="$$id$$">
      </script>
    </form>
```

esto es mi app.js, cuando corro el programa del lado del servidor utilizando node app.js y apreto el boton pagar me tira un error que dice "Oh no, algo anduvo mal", pero en la terminal ni en ningun otro lado me aparece algun error mas especifico.

```
const mercadopago = require('mercadopago');
const express = require('express')
const ejs = require('ejs')
const app = express()

app.listen('3000')

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.render('index')
})
// Agrega credenciales
mercadopago.configure({
    access_token: 'CLAVE'
});

// Crea un objeto de preferencia
let preference = {
    items: [{
        title: 'Mi producto',
        unit_price: 100,
        quantity: 1,
    }]
};

mercadopago.preferences.create(preference)
    .then(function (response) {
        // Este valor reemplazará el string "$$init_point$$" en tu HTML
        global.init_point = response.body.init_point;
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Asegurate de estar usando dos **usuarios de prueba** y **no tener ninguna sesion de mercadopago activa** en el navegador a la hora de hacer las pruebas.

Para generar los usuarios podes seguir el instructivo:
https://www.mercadopago.com.uy/developers/es/guides/online-payments/checkout-pro/test-integration/

De esos dos usuarios uno lo vas a usar como **Vendedor** y otro **Comprador**.

Cuando tengas el **Vendedor** te logueas con sus credenciales en la web de mercadpago y obtenes el API Token de ese usuario para ponerlo en tu codigo.
https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/panel/credentials

Con eso deberia ser suficiente para que levante el formulario.
Despues podes loguearte con el usuario **Comprador** para realizar un pago de prueba.

Answer (score 0):

Me encontre con varias situaciones en la que recibi este error.

1. Estar en ambiente de test y logueado con una cuenta de vendedor cuando quiero probar una compra.
2. Desarrollando desde un pais y queriendo implementar en otro.. ej. mercadopago.com.ar/...
   vs mercadopago.CL (no lleva .com) ademas si se deja en Argentina tambien falla.

Comment: ¿Esto es una solución o un comentario?